Unable to launch activity in Cordova app from custom plugin
I'm trying to launch a custom activity from my custom Cordova plugin but I am getting the following error:
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.outsystemsenterprise.fidelidadep10.MyFidelidade/com.fidelidade.meetingdoctors.MeetingDoctorsChatActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31 in android:layout/screen_toolbar: Binary XML file line #31 in android:layout/screen_toolbar: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4322)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2685)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8893)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:608)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31 in android:layout/screen_toolbar: Binary XML file line #31 in android:layout/screen_toolbar: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31 in android:layout/screen_toolbar: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:882)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1034)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:989)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1151)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1112)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:700)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:544)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:491)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onResourcesLoaded(DecorView.java:2942)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2876)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2939)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:2217)
    at androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge.enable(EdgeToEdge.kt:75)
    at androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge.enable$default(EdgeToEdge.kt:71)
    at com.fidelidade.meetingdoctors.MeetingDoctorsChatActivity.onCreate(MeetingDoctorsChatActivity.kt:16)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8944)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8913)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1456)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4146)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4322)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2685)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8893)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:608)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 13: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x1010433 a=1}, theme={InheritanceMap=[id=0x103024candroid:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar, id=0x103024bandroid:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark, id=0x1030248android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material, id=0x1030247android:style/ThemeOverlay], Themes=[android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar, forced, com.outsystemsenterprise.fidelidadep10.MyFidelidade:style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat, forced, com.outsystemsenterprise.fidelidadep10.MyFidelidade:style/Theme.AppCompat.Empty, forced, android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.DarkActionBar, forced]}
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:1007)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:991)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5988)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:712)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:99)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:94)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:89)
    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(ActionBarContainer.java:74)

Below is the custom activity class in my plugin:
package com.fidelidade.meetingdoctors

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat
import com.meetingdoctors.chat.views.professionallist.ProfessionalListFragment
import com.meetingdoctors.chat.views.professionallist.ProfessionalListener
import com.outsystemsenterprise.fidelidadep10.MyFidelidade.R

class MeetingDoctorsChatActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_meeting_doctors_chat)
        val professionalList = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.professionalList) as ProfessionalListFragment
        professionalList.setProfessionalListListener(object: ProfessionalListener {
            override fun onProfessionalClick(
                professionalId: Long,
                speciality: String,
                hasAccess: Boolean,
                isSaturated: Boolean
            ): Boolean {
                Log.d("ProfessionalList", "clicked")
                return true
            }

            override fun onListLoaded() {
                Log.d("ProfessionalList", "list loaded")
            }

            override fun onUnreadMessageCountChange(unreadMessageCount: Long) {
                Log.d("ProfessionalList", "Unread message count changed")
            }
        }
        )
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }
    }
}

Below is the activity XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MeetingDoctorsChatActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/professionalList"
        class="com.meetingdoctors.chat.views.professionallist.ProfessionalListFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>

In my AndroidManifest.xml I'm declaring the following activity:
<activity 
            android:name="com.fidelidade.meetingdoctors.MeetingDoctorsChatActivity" 
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat" />

I have tried both disabling and enabling "enableEdgeToEdge" but the error is the same.
